# Listings package lstinline command has strange spacing behaviour after double quotation mark

Tags: spacing, listings

I'm having problems with spacing after double quotation mark in lstinline. I've identified combinations of `morestring={[b]"}` and `basicstyle=\ttfamily`, which all behaves in manners, I cannot understand. Can anyone tell me, if this is a bug in listings or in my understanding of how to use it? E.g., the latex code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\noindent Here is an example of gobbling spaces after quotes in lstinline. I am testing the combinations of with and without '[b]"' and ttfamily fonts:

\begin{description}
\item[No arguments: 2nd space is removed]~\\
  \begin{description}
  \item[0:] \lstinline !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3!
  \item[1:] \lstinline !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3!
  \item[2:] \lstinline !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3!
  \item[3:] \lstinline !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3!
  \end{description}
\item[{[b]"}: 1st space is removed]~\\
  \begin{description}
  \item[0:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"}] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3!
  \item[1:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"}] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3!
  \item[2:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"}] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3!
  \item[3:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"}] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3!
  \end{description}
\item[ttfamily: more than 1 space removed]~\\
   \begin{description}
  \item[0:] \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3!
  \item[1:] \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3!
  \item[2:] \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3!
  \item[3:] \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3!
  \end{description}
\item[{[b]"} and ttfamily - first 2 spaces are removed]~\\
   \begin{description}
  \item[0:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"},basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3!
  \item[1:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"},basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3!
  \item[2:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"},basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3!
  \item[3:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"},basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3!
  \end{description}
\end{description}
Which is different when using begin-end-lstlisting, no arguments:
\begin{lstlisting}
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3 
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

gives all different output, where the begin-end-lstlisting last, is what I would have expected:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

What about using the `keepspaces` key?

> keepspaces=true tells the package not to drop spaces to fix column
>   alignment and always converts tabulators to spaces.

You just have to add this line:

```
\lstset{keepspaces=true}
```

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{keepspaces=true} % add this line
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is an example of gobbling spaces after quotes in lstinline. I am testing the combinations of with and without '[b]"' and ttfamily fonts:

\begin{description}
\item[No arguments: 2nd space is removed]~\\
  \begin{description}
  \item[0:] \lstinline !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3!
  \item[1:] \lstinline !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3!
  \item[2:] \lstinline !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3!
  \item[3:] \lstinline !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3!
  \end{description}
\item[{[b]"}: 1st space is removed]~\\
  \begin{description}
  \item[0:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"}] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3!
  \item[1:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"}] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3!
  \item[2:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"}] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3!
  \item[3:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"}] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3!
  \end{description}
\item[ttfamily: more than 1 space removed]~\\
   \begin{description}
  \item[0:] \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3!
  \item[1:] \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3!
  \item[2:] \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3!
  \item[3:] \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3!
  \end{description}
\item[{[b]"} and ttfamily - first 2 spaces are removed]~\\
   \begin{description}
  \item[0:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"},basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3!
  \item[1:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"},basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3!
  \item[2:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"},basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3!
  \item[3:] \lstinline[morestring={[b]"},basicstyle=\ttfamily] !printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3!
  \end{description}
\end{description}
Which is different when using begin-end-lstlisting, no arguments:
\begin{lstlisting}
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3 
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: I confirm, that works too. It still seems like a work-around though. Thanks, Jon

Comment: For me this still doesn't quite work if there are multiple spaces in a row, it still compresses them partially. Combining this with protecting the spaces (`\ \ \ `) works for me, though a bit cludgy.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution: turn on showspaces and replace visible space character with a regular space character:

```
\lstset{showspaces=true}
\makeatletter
\def\lst@visiblespace{ }
\makeatother
```

Not pretty, but it works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot comment, let me suggest not a solution but an alternative to this issue: the [`minted`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) package. It's a very powerful hightlighting pacakge with makes use of Pygments and `fancyvrb`. Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\noindent Here is an example of gobbling spaces after quotes in lstinline. I am testing the combinations of with and without '[b]"' and ttfamily fonts:

\begin{description}
    \item[No arguments: 2nd space is removed]~\\
    \begin{description}
        \item[0:] \mint{fsharp}{!printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3!}
        \item[1:] \mint{fsharp}{!printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3!}
        \item[2:] \mint{fsharp}{!printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3!}
        \item[3:] \mint{fsharp}{!printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3!}
    \end{description}
\end{description}
Which is different when using begin-end-lstlisting, no arguments:
\begin{minted}{fsharp}
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"3
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d" 3
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"  3 
printfn "Test 1 2 \%d"   3 
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The catch here is that `minted` has to run with `-shell-escape` and I'm not quite sure but maybe it needs to have python installed. Still, I truly recomend it as there's a bunch of predefined styles you can change just by preselecting it in the preamble.